# Sticky footer is hiding content at the bottom of my website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a sticky footer for a Wordpress website. I gave the section the ID `#formfooter` and used the following CSS:

```
#formfooter{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Now I want to expand the [website's](http://www.naotech.com/he) height accordingly. When the user scrolls down to the bottom the sticky footer covers the content at the bottom. I How can I make it scroll down a bit further?

Comment: In this case one usually gives the content  a margin: `#content {margin-bottom: heightOfFooterPx;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your content is displayed behind your sticky bar. 
You need your container (ie what contain your informations) to have a `margin-bottom` so it won't display informations behind your sticky content.

So let's say your layout look kind of like this :

```
<body>
 <div class="container">

   THE CONTENT OF YOUR HTML PAGE

 </div>
 <div class="sticky-footer">
      YOUR STICKY FOOTER, let's say it take 20px as height
 </div> 
</body>
```

You will need to do something like :

```
.container {
   margin-bottom: 20px; (i.e. the size of you sticky content)
}
```

Comment: What if the footer has non-deterministic height?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is to manually add the sticky footer to footer.php and a div above it to play with the height to get the best result!

PS: The website does scroll really fast! Can be not user friendly like this. Do take a look at the scroll speed settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `#formfooter` position (use sticky, not fixed). This should allow your full page content to be scrollable/viewable.

```
#formfooter{
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```